# convert LPVOID IN CHAR ERROR C2440: =

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory, memory-management

How do I convert a LPVOID to char ?

```
char * pCacheMap;

pCacheMap = MapViewOfFile(hCacheMapping,FILE_MAP_READ|FILE_MAP_WRITE,0,0,0);
```

Error:

```
    3   IntelliSense: a value of type "LPVOID" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char *" 
Error   1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'LPVOID' to 'char *'
```

Comment: What in that error message is unclear? There is no implicit conversion from `LPVOID` to `char*` like you may expect from a language like C. A cast will be required for C++.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cast.  Since LPVOID is a synonym for void * it is legal to cast it to any other pointer type so:

```
pCacheMap = static_cast<char *>(MapViewOfFile(...));
```

will work.